# Y-axis labels for Bluff Javascript library

Tags: javascript, graph, precision

So, I'm using the [fabulous Bluff library](http://bluff.jcoglan.com/) to put up some graphs from a Rails app. I wanted to customize the Y-axis labels to display fewer decimal digits of precision. Anybody got a clue how to do that? I could try to analyze the "compressed" version of the library and hack it in there, but I'd rather use the API if I can!

TIA,

rw

Comment: FYI I have raised two related issues on github (https://github.com/jcoglan/bluff/issues/17 and https://github.com/jcoglan/bluff/issues/16). Perhaps you'd like to add your question there too.